# Writing custom data analysis program

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a number of large datasets (10GBs) each with data fetched from a NoSQL database that I have remotely downloaded on my desktop. I would like to write a Python program to run some custom data analysis (plots - preferably interactive) and export custom reports in html or pdf.

I was wondering how people do the following:

1) Store the data. For the moment I have plain text files (each file has rows of a fixed number of columns - most of the data are categorical). Would it make sense to save those in some database (SQL) or hdf5? Any hints on which is preferrable?

2) Which plotting library would you propose for the graphs? I have seen about bookeh and matplotlib supports interactive widgets but I don't know what people normally use.

3) Could I export the analysis results in an IPython notebook and then in html programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Store the data. For the moment I have plain text files (each file
>   has rows of a fixed number of columns - most of the data are
>   categorical). Would it make sense to save those in some database (SQL)
>   or hdf5? Any hints on which is preferable?

**Yes,** it would make sense to store in a local database, rather than using large csv/text files. As you say that the data is derived from a NoSQL source, I assume unstructured data. So, using a SQL/relational store is out of question. As you say you are using Python, I would suggest you use [TinyDB](http://tinydb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is both light-weight and easy to handle.

> 2) Which plotting library would you propose for the graphs? I have
>   seen about bookeh and matplotlib supports interactive widgets but I
>   don't know what people normally use.

Matplotlib would be good enough. Actually, this question is more opinion-based than anything else. There are a lot of visualization libraries you can use, like Bokeh, Seaborn, etc.

> 3) Could I export the analysis results in an IPython notebook and then
>   in html programmatically?

**Yes**, you can do the analytics directly in an Ipython notebook(Jupyter), which also supports Markdown and HTML cells.

In addition, you can also use [widgets and interactive visualization with Jupyter Ipy notebooks](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets) and Matplotlib.  [Tutorials for the same](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Index.ipynb)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer! The data is post-processed to be structured, I will try TinyDB, never heard of it before. I read some people have been using SQLite with mixed opinions about speed. Regarding the plotting, I guess I need to have a custom program that uses IPython since I will have to internally read the data from SQL, run some standard functions that should not be exported at the report to send to my users, right?

Comment: Yeah, right!  If you don't want to use Ipython, then you can write a [Luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) script for the workflow, and connect the whole thing to a server for visualization!